# jquery javascript concatenate/variable issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html table inside of a form tags.
When I click on the a cell inside of the table jquery gives me the “id” attr of the cell.
I save the “id” attr to a variable called id.
When I alert “id” the id shows:

```
    alert(id); //outputs 39
```

However on the very next line I have

```
      term1 = $form.find( "input[name='firstoneinput_" + id +"']").val();

 alert(term1); //outputs undefinined // it should output input 
                                       value with name attribute 
                                      of "firstoneinput_39"
```

why is the alert outputting undefined.  Btw I put real values in to the text fields also.
HTML

```
                <!doctype html>
                         <html lang="en">
                         <head>
                            <meta charset="utf-8">
                            <title>jQuery.post demo</title>
                            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
                         </head>
                         <body>
                            <form action="comments.php" id="nameForm">
                               <table border='1'>
                              <tr>
               <td><input type="text" class="hidden" name="firstoneinput_1_25" id="25" placeholder="firstoneinput_1_25"> </td>
    <td>  <input type="text" class="hidden" name="firsttwoinput_1_26" id="26" placeholder="firsttwoinput_1_26"></td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td>  <input type="text" class="hidden" name="firstoneinput_2_27" id="27" placeholder="firstoneinput_2_27"> </td>
    <td>  <input type="text" class="hidden" name="firsttwoinput_2_28" id="28" placeholder="firsttwoinput_2_28"></td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td>  <input type="text" class="hidden" name="firstoneinput_3_29" id="29" placeholder="firstoneinput_3_29"> </td>
    <td>  <input type="text" class="hidden" name="firsttwoinput_3_30" id="30" placeholder="firsttwoinput_3_30"></td>

</tr>
               <tr>
    <td>  <input type="text" class="hidden" name="firstoneinput_4_31" id="31" placeholder="firstoneinput_4_31"> </td>
    <td>  <input type="text" class="hidden" name="firsttwoinput_4_32" id="32" placeholder="firsttwoinput_4_32"></td>

</tr>



            </table>
           <td> <input type="submit" value="search"></td>

            </form>
           <!-- the result of the search will be rendered inside this div -->
                <div id="result"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
               <script>


               $(document).ready(function(){

                var id = 0;

               $('table tr td').click(function(){


              id = $(this).children("input[class='hidden']").attr("id");
                 return id;

                    });



           $( "#nameForm" ).submit(function( event ) {

           // Stop form from submitting normally
              event.preventDefault();

       // Get some values from elements on the page:
               var $form = $( this );




            term1 = $form.find( "input[name='firstoneinput_" + id +"']").val();

                 alert(term1); <---alerts undefined even thou I put in form values
                   alert(id); <----alerts ok the id
```

Comment: you need to do `$("#form").find`... or `$(".form").find`...

Comment: does $form have proper element in it ?

Comment: Could you please post the HTML?

Comment: Please post your HTML

Comment: Is `$form` an jQuery object? If not you have to do like @Sualkcin says

Comment: it works, if $form is defined http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/KWHae/

Comment: `name` is not the same thing as `id`. Is the `name` set to `firstoneinput_39` as well as the `id`?

Comment: Does the element have a value at the point at which that jQuery is run?

Comment: I save the form id in a $form variable

Comment: Im basically trying to get javascript to give me the value of an input field after submission.  So I am grabbing the name attribute 'firstoneinput_'  but I need to some how get the number that follows in the name attribute (ie. firstoneinput_1 firstoneinput_2).

Comment: Perhaps because your form doesn't have a field with name "firstoneinput_39" ? To begin with all names in your HTML are defined in format "firstoneinput_number_number" e.g. "firstoneinput_1_25"

Answer (score 0):

### New answer

This will always alert undefined ...

```
alert(term1); // < ---alerts undefined even thou I put in form values
```

... because you're looking for **firstoneinput_XX** ...

```
$form.find( "input[name='firstoneinput_" + id +"']").val();
```

... but your actual input elements have the name convention **firstoneinput_X_XX**.

```
<input ... name="firsttwoinput_1_26" ... />
```

### - - - Previous answer - - 8-< - - -

Html:

```
<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td id='39'>Klick</td>
    </tr>
  </table>    
  <input name="firstoneinput_39" value="the_uber_value"/>
</form>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('td').click(function() {
    alert($('input[name="firstoneinput_' + this.id + '"]').val());
  });
});
```

Magic:
http://jsfiddle.net/McNull/4BDmh/